# Придаточное изъяснительное перед главной частью

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, спп, сложное-предложение

*Всюду говорят: связи решают всё. Но как именно их заводить — никто не объясняет.*

*Всюду говорят: связи решают всё. Но как именно их заводить, никто не объясняет.*

Обычно придаточное изъяснительное стоит после главной части. Когда имеет место инверсия, такая необычная структура обязывает ставить тире или без интонационного и логического выделения можно поставить и запятую?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы бы пояснили, как возникла мысль о том, что такая структура обязывает ставить тире. По-моему, запятая — стандартный вариант в любом случае, а тире служит для интонационного и логического выделения.

Comment: Вы, кажется, сами на это правило как-то ссылались (https://dict.nsu.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=12&chapterid=71).

Comment: По-моему, такая структура позволяет, но не обязывает  ставить тире.